# install packages error

Tags: r, install.packages

Here is my annoying problem.When I am trying to install packages by:
`install.packages("multicore")`

I get the error:

> error at if (nzchar(SHLIB_LIBADD)) SHLIB_LIBADD else character() : the length of parameter is zero

Here `multicore` is not the only package that I can not install.I have the same error for many other packages(but not all of the packages) such as `Rcpp` etc.

I am using `debian jessie` with `R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06) -- "Warm Puppy"` .I have run into this problem for a while.And it is really annoying.Even if I use the R which compiled from the source code it still has the same problem.

Appreciate any suggestion!

Comment: i think that this package is now replaced by `parallel`, which is built-in in R. Therefore, you don't need to install this package to use for example `doparallel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing package management is tricky and Debian tends to ignore it.

try instead

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-multicore
```

which I found by going to [Debian Packages](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages) and searching descriptions for `multicore "GNU R"`

You can check it is the package you want [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/r-cran-multicore).

Comment: Thank you so much for your hint!Really works!It is just the mixing package management problem.Good to fix it!

Comment: I do have another question: what is the difference between the packages downloaded from the `CRAN` and the packages installed by `apt-get`?As described by debian official webpage `Additionally, several thousand extension "packages" are available from CRAN, the Comprehensive R Archive Network, many also as Debian packages, named 'r-cran-<name>'`,but I do installed some package twice from the `CRAN` and from `apt-get`

Comment: By downloading a package from apt-get, Debian "knows" about it, so makes sure packages are in Debian's default PATH and won't install a duplicate. CRAN is a separate way to install packages. It would be possible that CRAN could install a package in one directory and Debian in another, or CRAN install in a folder not in a Debian user's PATH. That said, it is quite common for the "stable" packages in Debian to be 1-3 years old. In this case though the multicore on Deb is version 1-7-2 and CRAN is 1-7.